# split operation in oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

Basically I am fetching the TRIGGER code like below.

```
dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'trigger_name');
```

The output of above line is something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER "owner"."trigger_name" BEFORE DELETE ON roles FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.read_client_info (acct_utils.trigger_enabled);
IF acct_utils.trigger_enabled <> 'F' THEN
  INSERT INTO qatable (ID,KEY, OBJECT, KEYTYPE, TYPE, OBJ_DEF_ID, WHENCREATED, WHENDELETED, DELETEDBY) VALUES(
    :old.cny#,
    :old.record#,
    'roles',
    null,
    :old.name,
    null,
    :old.whencreated,
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('TMCtx', 'USERKEY')
  );
END IF;
END trigger_name;
ALTER TRIGGER "owner"."trigger_name" ENABLE
```

I am trying to fetch only the "insert into qatable" statement using following statement

```
select substr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'trigger_name'), 
    instr(upper(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'trigger_name')), 'INSERT INTO qatable ('),
    instr(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'trigger_name'), ';', instr(upper(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'trigger_name')), 'INSERT INTO qatable'), 1) -
          instr(upper(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'trigger_name')), 'INSERT INTO qatable') + 1) from dual;
```

The output of the above query is an insert statement either

```
INSERT INTO qatable (ID,KEY, OBJECT, KEYTYPE, TYPE, OBJ_DEF_ID, WHENCREATED, WHENDELETED, DELETEDBY) VALUES(
    :old.ID,
    :old.KEY,
    'roles',
    null,
    :old.type,
    null,
    :old.whencreated,
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('TMCtx', 'USERKEY')
  );
```

OR

```
  INSERT INTO qatable (ID,KEY, KEYTYPE, TYPE, OBJ_DEF_ID, WHENCREATED, WHENDELETED, DELETEDBY) VALUES(
    :old.ID,
    :old.KEY,
    null,
    :old.type,
    null,
    :old.whencreated,
    (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('TMCtx', 'USERKEY')
  );
```

depending upon the trigger name.

For few trigger the value to the field TYPE is null and for others the value is getting passes. I have requirement like if some value is getting inserted into 'Type' , I have to save it in array or list and send it back through procedure.

desc qatable; 
gives following result

```
Name            Null?       Type         
-----------     --------    ------------ 
ID              NOT NULL     NUMBER(15)   
KEY             NOT NULL     NUMBER(15)   
OBJECT          NOT NULL     VARCHAR2(30) 
KEYTYPE                      CHAR(2)      
TYPE                         VARCHAR2(60) 
OBJ_DEF_ID                   NUMBER(8)    
WHENDELETED                  DATE         
DELETEDBY                    NUMBER(8)    
WHENCREATED                  DATE         
RECORDNO        NOT NULL     NUMBER
```

Comment: Please update your question with an [MCVE] including the DDL for your tables and sufficient information to let us know what you are trying to achieve (as a pair of `INSERT` statements and a very vague description is insufficient for us to understand what you want, much less help you).

Comment: @MT0 I have updated the question. Hope I will get help from the details.

Comment: Interesting. Was this same question asked by you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443296/sub-string-in-oracle

Comment: How is this a 'split operation'? Normally that refers to loading an array from a delimited string (e.g. in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)). The question seems to be about extracting a single pattern.

Comment: Can't you just make a trigger on `qatable`, that does what you want, when something other than `NULL` was  inserted for `TYPE`?